# OpenVPN 2.4 tls-crypt and dh vs elliptic curve

Tags: ssl, vpn, openvpn

1. If I understand correctly from [OpenVPN 2.4 manual](https://openvpn.net/community-resources/reference-manual-for-openvpn-2-4/), if one is using `ECDH TLS cipher suites` then they can set `dh none`. This will have same security level (or better) as using dh key, is this a correct assumption?
2. About the tls-auth, the manual says "Use –tls-crypt instead if you want to use the key file to not only authenticate, but also encrypt the TLS control channel.".

Currently I do **NOT** have `tls-auth` or `tls-crypt` setup in configuration but in logs I see

```
Control Channel: TLSv1.2, cipher TLSv1.2 ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384, 521 bit EC, curve: secp521r1
```

Does that mean that `tls-crypt` option is NOT necessary if elliptic curve is used? or what additional security does `tls-crypt` add if control channel is already encrypted even without this option? and does it make any difference if one is using UDP or TCP?

Thanks!

Comment: Your question actually contains 3 questions, so it may fall under the _"Needs more focus"_ category. If you split your question, I'll split my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `ECDH` and `DH` are both variants of the [Diffie-Hellman key exchange](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_key_exchange) and require an [abelian group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abelian_group) with computationally complex division. However:

   - Generating good finite fields for the `DH` algorithm is relatively easy (though time consuming), so OpenVPN asks you to do it with `openssl dhparam` and provide the result with `dh <filename>`. This way you don't use the predefined groups that might be subject to the [Logjam attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logjam_(computer_security)), which is within NSA budget. However, factorization in finite fields is a well understood subject, so `DH` is slower than `ECDH` with a comparable level of security.
   - Generating good elliptic curves is difficult, so you **must** use the [predefined ones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic-curve_cryptography#Domain_parameters) and there is no `ecdh <filename>` option. As for the `dh` option, you can use `dh none` with elliptic curves. Division on an elliptic curve is not very well developed, so to have a similar level of security as `DH` nowadays you need smaller curves.
2. Even without the `tls-auth` or `tls-crypt` options, your **data** will **always** be encrypted. The `TLS` protocol encrypts data with a key obtained in a key exchange, as in the previous point. These options control what to do with the 4 packets of the [TLS Handshake](http://blog.fourthbit.com/2014/12/23/traffic-analysis-of-an-ssl-slash-tls-session/):

   Usually (as in the `HTTPS` protocol) they are unencrypted since the peers don't have any prior knowledge of each other. But with OpenVPN you have an advantage: you can configure on the server and all authorized clients a common [symmetric key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric-key_algorithm), which will sign or encrypt these 4 packets.

   This will allow the server to drop all not signed `ClientHello` messages, **before** even allocating resources for the **computationally heavy** `TLS` protocol. Hence, it will more easily survive a `DDoS` attack, where an attacker initiates thousands of connections at once.

   Using `tls-auth` is similar to configuring a common `WEP` key on a Wi-Fi network, together with a per-client `WPA-Enterprise` authentication. The main difference is that `WEP` encryption is heavily broken, whereas `HMAC` signatures or `AES` encryption isn't. Therefore you won't be able to reproduce the aforementioned configuration on a Wi-Fi network (it is not supported by software).
3. The `UDP` vs `TCP` choice is a no brainer: use `UDP` whenever possible. `TCP` guarantees that all emitted IP packets will not be lost and will arrive in the order they were sent.

   This sounds nice, but your `VPN` tunnel will also transport inner `TCP` connections. If a packet is lost, both the `OpenVPN` client and the program that established the inner `TCP` connection will start **retransmitting**. However the retransmitted packets from the inner connection will arrive to their destination **after** those retransmitted by `OpenVPN` were delivered. This causes unnecessary network traffic.

**Edit**: A comparison between the strength of `DH` and `ECDH` is available e.g. on [Keylength.com](https://www.keylength.com/en/4/):

- the required size of the `DH` group is in the column `Discrete Logarithm Group`,
- the size of an elliptic curve with equivalent strength is in the column `Elliptic Curve`,

For example the following configuration for elliptic curves:

```
ecdh-curve prime256v1
```

is equivalent to generating `DH` parameters with `openssl dhparam -out /etc/openvpn/dh.pem 3072` and using:

```
dh /etc/openvpn/dh.pem
```

The values provided by the NIST Recommendations correspond roughly to [OpenSSL security levels](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man3/SSL_CTX_get_security_level.html#DEFAULT-CALLBACK-BEHAVIOUR). The default security level is **level 1**, which means a minimum of `2048` bits for the `DH` groups and `224` bits for elliptic curves. You can increase it using the `tls-cipher` option (cf. [OpenSSL documentation](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man1/openssl-ciphers.html#CIPHER-LIST-FORMAT) for the format). E.g. setting:

```
tls-cipher DEFAULT:@SECLEVEL=4
```

will cause OpenVPN connections to fail, until you adjust the two settings above to the required group sizes (`7680` for `DH` and `384` for `ECDH`).

Comment: What I wanted to ask about TCP/UDP was related to tls-crypt as manual says it can hide the existence of the server when UDP is used but it can't do it when TCP is used, But your answer points to some other benefits as lower load on server if an attack ever occurs (unless the attacker knows the tls-crypt key?). Thanks. I will mark it soon as correct answer if there is not any better answers.

Comment: Closing a `TCP` connection requires sending a `RST` or `FIN` packet, while to close a `UDP` _"connection"_ the server just stops responding. That's what the manual is probably referring to. But a `TCP` connection gives you also a worse performance during **normal** operation, which you'll notice as soon as there are multiple connections using the VPN tunnel or the network connection is not perfect (it always isn't).

Comment: Yes I agree with you that UDP is probably better if you need performance. About the DH setting, it would be nice to know which curves are equal or better than default OpenVPN suggestion `openssl dhparam -out dh2048.pem 2048` is there a comparison? How can one know if it is better to use `dh none` or the dh2048.pem instead? I am not sure if this question makes sense... ?

Comment: I added some more information about key sizes in the answer.